# Could self referrals be counted as new visits?

Tags: google-analytics

our website was using absolute url before(such as "www.example.com/?action=splash"), and now we switched to relative urls(such as "/?action=splash")

We know that we were not doing the correct thing before. We noticed that by using absolute urls, we are doing self referrals when user click from one page on our site to another page on our site.

However, since we changed to relative urls, our visits dropped sharply based on Google Analytics, therefore, **we wonder if self referring were counted as new visits**.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics is blind to whether the links on your page are relative or absolute.

The likeliest cause of self-referral, though, is if you're changing subdomains between pageviews without having set `_setDomainName` to a compatible value.

When you *do* have self-referral (which is bad), it *does* indeed artificially inflate your visit count. So, fixing a self-referral problem will lead to a fall in visitor count. (But, it will be more accurate.)

Example: if I arrive via Google, I'm now a visit attributed to google. Then, if I go from www.example.com to secure.example.com without the GA tags being configured properly with `_gaq.push(["_setDomainName","example.com"]);`, then I'm now treated as a visitor with his second visit, this time referred from www.example.com. ie, self-referrals cause duplication of visit counts.

If you're seeing less self-referral, its not because of the absolute/referral difference, unless the absolute URLs were being inconsistent with, say, whether they included www.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way Google Analytics works, the referrer should really not affect anything like that. It is more probable that you broke something else when you changed your URLs.